# base.EndInvoke throws timeoutException when table is 1MB

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight application which adds 120 rows to a SQL table once an hour. This is done by a WCF service (using LINQ to SQL). After 12 hours of running the program, it throws exception in References.cs (which is created automatically). This is the exception message:

```
The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:64739/SQLService.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

If I stop the application and rerun it here it will add the 13th hour data and throws the exception on 14th. The problem might be related to SQL table size, since it throws the first timeout exception when the table size becomes almost 1MB. Any ideas?

This is where the exception is catched:

```
public void EndAddTables(System.IAsyncResult result) {

                object[] _args = new object[0];
                base.EndInvoke("AddTables", _args, result);

 }
```

And this is the AddTables code:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public void AddTables(short ID, string temperature, string humidity,
                string wind, ...)
    {
        WeatherDataClassDataContext db = new WeatherDataClassDataContext();
        Weather_Info row = new Weather_Info();


        row.OfficeID = ID;
        row.temperature = temperature;
        row.humidity = humidity;

        db.Weather_Infos.InsertOnSubmit(row);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, db.Weather_Infos);
    }
```